# X mouse button control, reassign MMB to caps lock

Tags: remapping, button-remapping, xmouse

My MMB is broken, I'm trying to make caps lock activate the middle mouse button, but I can't figure out how to do it without extra buttons on the mouse (which I don't have). Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: win 10 pro 22H2 19045.4170

Comment: Though XMouse Button Control is a great tool, this might be better done with AutoHotkey: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/MouseClick.htm .

Answer (score 0):

The free [AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/) is a better tool.

The following example script will map
<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to the middle mouse button:

```
CapsLock::MButton
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)